# How many ways to shoot three columns of balloons containing $x,y,z$ balloons respectively.

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose there are three columns of balloons and the columns contain $x,y,z$ balloons respectively. A shooter wants to shoot the balloons. For this he chooses a column and shoots the lowest balloon of the column. In how many ways he can shoot all the balloons.

My attempt:
I relate the number of ways of shooting with arrangement of $x$ elements of one kind, $y$ elements of second kind and $z$ elements of the third kind. Hence the answer is $\dfrac{(x+y+z)!}{x!y!z!}$. But, here I consider that the order of arrangement doesn't matter. But, in case of shooting, the shooter shoots the lowest balloon. But, does that really matter, as he could shoot any balloon for any column.

But, I am confused about this answer. Is it alright? Please help. Thank you.

Comment: I don't if this is correct but he can choose any one column in 3 ways. Now, he has to shoot the lowest balloon first. So, we can consider it as if the first element is fixed. Rest $x-1$ elements can be arranged in $x-1$ ways and similarly for the other two columns.

Comment: It is a different way of approaching. It may be correct but I am myself confused, so cannot tell whether it is correct or not.

Comment: What is the answer?

Comment: It's not given.

Comment: Regarding your approach, you haven't taken into account the fact that the lowest balloon has to be shot first. Also, the column which he selects first matters.

Comment: I think your answer is correct. The number of permutations of $x+y+z$ things is $(x+y+z)!$. But that counts $x!$ orderings of the balloons in the first column, of which only one is valid, so you have to divide by $x!$; similarly, by $y!$ and by $z!$.